# How can I list the data of foreign keys linked to the id of the table?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

What I want to do is create 4 interconnected progressive category classes.I don't know if the method I did is correct. Unfortunately I have been reading the document for days. but I haven't made much progress

Over the 'company' class how can I query all data belonging to the 'DepartmentalUnit' class?

```
create_table_company= '''CREATE TABLE company(
ID SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY , 
NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
); '''

create_table_department = '''CREATE TABLE department (
ID SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY , 
NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
company_id BIGINT, 
FOREIGN KEY(company_id) REFERENCES COMPANY(id)); '''

create_table_department_unit = '''CREATE TABLE department_unit(
ID SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY , 
NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
department_id BIGINT,
FOREIGN KEY(department_id) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(id)); 

create_table_department_unit_categroy = '''CREATE TABLE department_unit_category(
ID SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY , 
NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
department_unit_id BIGINT,
FOREIGN KEY(department_unit_id) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT_UNİT(id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
   c.id, c.name,  du.*
FROM 
   company AS c
JOIN 
   department AS d 
ON
   c.id = d.company_id 
JOIN 
  department_unit AS du 
ON 
   du.department_id = d.id
;
```

**UPDATE**

The above query works to get the `department_unit` information by connecting the tables by their common fields. In this case the `company` table finds the `department` information for each company by using the `company_id` field in `department` that links back to a company. Once the departments for a company are found the department units for each department is found by using the `department_id` field in `department_unit` to link back to the `department` table. The end result is a chain that connects a company to its department units.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem, but I guess I don't understand. More precisely, I cannot understand. I don't know how to handle the database issue? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @sananesanane. You will have to be more explicit about what the database issue is?

Comment: I'm sorry my english is not very good. I think I wrote wrong. I have to design a database and write queries. However, I cannot understand database related subjects. Although I read the documents.

Comment: I would recommend finding a  beginners book and/or tutorial in your language that goes over the basics of `SQL` databases. What you want covers a lot of information and is outside the scope of an `SO` answer. I will update my answer to explain why this particular query works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I need to study more